# Ftp using TcpClient in C#

Tags: c#, ftp, command-prompt, tcpclient, windows-forms-designer

```
TcpClient tcp= new TcpClient();
tcp.Connect("192.168.10.1",21);
tcp.GetStream();

if(tcp.Connected.ToString()=="True")
{
    NetworkStream ns=tcp.GetStream();

    using(NetworkStream stream-tcp.GetStream())
    {
         byte[] username=System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user+"\r\n")
         stream.Wrtie(username,0,user.Length);

         byte[] password=System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass+"\r\n")
         stream.Wrtie(password,0,pass.Length);
         MessageBox.Show(""+ns.Read(data,0,data.Length)+"");
    }
}
```

I am using above code to ftp a router using tcpclient, it returns an error stating "530 please login with USER and PASS".

Comment: Yes, because you're not logging in with the commands USER and PASS. Read the RFC. You're also appending CRLF and then not sending them by using the wrong length and Wrtie is not a valid method. Don't write different code when asking what's wrong with your actual code.

Comment: Consider using [FtpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen can you briefly explain your point, please?

Comment: I thought I did: you're not sending what the RFC says the FTP protocol wants.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen sir its my own code. This is the code which is causing the error

Comment: No, it's not. This code wouldn't even compile due to many typos. And please don't compare booleans by using ToString() and string comparison...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you going to use the *TcpClient* class (like you are doing), then you will have to implement the FTP specification (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt).

However, I think it would be better to find an FTP client library to use instead.

Comment: Ad MickyD already mentioned, there's a perfectly good one inside the framework already, namely FtpWebRequest.